# How to set a connection timeout and add an AlertDialog for it

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connection, timeout, android-alertdialog

i create the following method in an AsyncTask innerc class to connect to internet and get a JSON file from the provided url. I'm experiencing problems if there is a bad connection, my app hangs for a lot of time waiting for connection...

```
        private JSONArray connectAndCreateJsonArray(String url) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonArray;
        }
```

I call this method from doInBackground() method. How to handle a connection timeout with an AlertDialog?

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
```

TimeOut until your Connection is established

```
int timeOutInMillis = 10*1000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOutInMillis);
```

sets the timeOut until your data received

```
int socketTimeOutinMillis = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, socketTimeOutinMillis);
```

create a client with the parameters

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I add AlertDialog for it thanks to the answer of NIPHIN. Using your code i get AlertDialog after 10 seconds or 15 seconds?

Comment: Depends on what u exactly want. if you want a connecitonTimeout after 15 seconds set : int timeOutInMillis = 15*1000; if you want your data to be at your client after 5 seconds set: int socketTimeOutinMillis = 5000; Just set the milliseconds how you like them. And btw: 0 miliseconds means default timeout!

Comment: You misunderstand me, sorry. I mean if i set 5 secs to first timeout and 5 secs to second timeout, the total waiting time is 5 or 10 secs?
In your example the total waiting time is 10 or 15 seconds?

Comment: then ur client has 5 seconds to connect to your server and 5 seconds to fetch data. But that doesnt mean he has allover 10 seconds. if he needs 2 seconds for connection he still just has 5 seconds for fetching data.

Comment: In this last case, if there is no connection to internet, the AlertDialog appears after 5 or 10 seconds?

Comment: if theres not connection to the internet, a exception will be thrown instantly i guess. Timeout just means if the server responds slowly, you can set the time how long you wanna wait for responses.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong. I mean if the connection is slow and the timeouts are 5 for connection and 10 for fetching... then the AlertDialog appears after 5 or 10 seconds?

Comment: you cant tell that that strictly. Example: your client needs 2 out of 5 seconds for connection to the server and 10 out of 10 seconds to fetch ( so not in time ), it will raise a exception after 12 seconds. You should still do some tests on this because i cant test this at the moment and i'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are attempting to connect to internet on your mainUI thread that causes your app to hang. spawn a separate thread for your connection. You could catch timeout exception and show a toast or alertdialog in respective catch block

catch (TimeoutException e) {

```
      String error = e.getMessage();    
        e.printStackTrace();  
         boolean errorflag=true;      
      return error ;
```

in postexecute show user this exception

Comment: I call my method in an AsyncTask inner class.

Comment: use timeoutexception in catch block as I mentioned

Comment: Unreachable catch block for TimeoutException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: There's no evidence here of connecting on the main thread: in fact that would throw a `NetworkingOnMainThreadException` of its own. The 'timeout exception' is `SocketTimeoutException`, unless the `HttpClient` has one of its own. -1

Comment: It seems to work, but i cannot use Toast or AlertDialog in doInBackground()... how to solve this?

Comment: did you see "boolean errorFlag" set to true in catch block. it tells us that an error has being captured.So the returning string contains the error message check for the errorflag set to true in postexecute() and display accordingly

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I used code posted by maffelbaffel. What is the timeout value with your code?

Comment: There is always a default timeout set but if you want more time you could use code posted by maffelbaffel. but generally dont make users wait as a best practise